# How can I split and reconnect large files?

Tags: mac, zip, cloud

I'm trying to upload 10 GB files to S3, but the files are too large.

So I'm looking for a program that will zip then split the file into multiple, smaller files.

Of course, I need the same program to enable me to reconnect the files

My preference is to have a Mac & PC program, but the Mac version is most important to me.

Comment: The classic way has been to split large files into .rar archives. Do you have a program that can split and rejoin .rar files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.hjsplit.org/
says it is supported by PC and MAC

there are loads of programs to split files, this one for the PC, called WinSplit http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,17120-order,1-page,1-c,alldownloads/description.html

Any binary file splitter, a program that just reads the binary of the file and doesn't interpret it, doesn't add or remove anything.
They should combine too.

Also, to combine them on a PC you can use copy /B file1.a+file2.a    then they end up totalled in file1.a so you may want to make a backup of file1.a if you want to keep it 'cos it'll get overwritten.  If you use copy /B ..+..+..+.. to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use 'uuencode' and 'split', both command line commands, then transfer the files, rejoin them with 'cat' and finally 'uudecode' them.